# Equation of motion for a driven mechanical oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

I'm trying to derive the differential equation for a driven **horizontal** mechanical oscillator.

If I suppose that a spring is fixed at one end and attached to a solid at the other end and that the solid is being driven directly, then using Newton's second law, it is simple to show that: $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+kx=Fsin(wt).$$

But where I am stuck is the case where the spring is attached to a solid at one end (let's call it S) and being driven at the other end (let's call it D). I can't find the same equation at all.

What makes it worse, is that using different methods, I find different results.

The first method I used was to apply Newton's second law to the solid and derive that: $$-k(x_S-x_D+l_0)=m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2} \Leftrightarrow m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2} + kx_S = k(l_0-x_D)$$ and i'm stuck here and can't prove that $k(l_0-x_D)=Fsin(wt).$

The second method I used is to apply Newton's second law to both the solid and the driven end of the spring:

at the driven end "D" : $Fsin(wt)-kX=0 $ where X is the total deformation of the spring and since D is a point and therefore massless then the sum of forces equals zero.

at the solid end "S" : $-kX = m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2}$ where X is the total deformation of the spring.

Combining both equations led me to : $Fsin(wt)=-m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2}$

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in both methods, and how to derive the correct equation of motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result when the equations of equilibrium are applied correctly is $F\sin(\omega t)=m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2}$.

It's a little hard to follow your question because you haven't specified where you're measuring all these $x$ values from. I think, based on some of your equations, that you're measuring all distances from the original mass position and that positive $x$ points from that position to the driven end. Let's say that the force points in that direction too.

Then, a force balance at the mass end gives $k(x_D-x_S-l_0)=m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2}$.

A force balance at the driven end gives $k(x_D-x_S-l_0)=F\sin(\omega t)$.

Thus, we obtain $F\sin(\omega t)=m\frac{d^2x_S}{dt^2}$, reflecting the fact that the driven surface (having no inertia) moves instantly and that the spring (having no inertia) compresses or extends instantly to transmit the driving force immediately to the mass.

For this reason, so-called seismic excitation problems usually involve a prescribed base *displacement*, rather than a prescribed base *force*, because the former gives richer results. I review the corresponding frequency response briefly in case 9 [here](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm).

Comment: If I use a base displacement rather than a base force, I will obtain an equation that is quite like the case when the mass is directly driven. How can two different equations describe the same movement depending on whether I use base displacement or force ? After all the movement is unique.

Comment: Why do you say it’s the same movement?

Comment: In order to create that displacement, there must be a force that creates it. So why working with displacement and force yields differents equations  for movement ?

Comment: Because the force required to obtain sin(ωt)
 displacement of the base isn't sin(ωt)
 when the base is connected to a spring and a mass. There's a phase shift involved.